# how to post the value in url using PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I am creating a web service. I have tried to write an URL but its throwing error. I am not getting where I am going wrong. I want to pass these variable values in url and depending on this i want to call the web service

```
<?php
if($_POST["occupation"] == '1'){
    $occupation = 'Salaried';
}
else{
    $occupation = 'Self+Employed';
}

$url = 'http://www.aaa.com/ajaxv2/getCompareResults.html?interestRateType='.$_POST["interestRateType"]'.&occupation='.$_POST["occupation"].'&offeringTypeId='.$_POST["offeringID"].'&city='.$_POST["city"].'&loanAmt='.$_POST["loanAmt"].'&age='.$_POST["age"];
echo $url;
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($result, true);

//print_r($json); 
//echo $json['resultList']['interestRateMin'];
$json_array = $json['resultList'];

print_r($json_array);

?>
```

Comment: could you post the error

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: Inproper Quotes issue. Try this, $url = 'http://www.aaa.com/ajaxv2/getCompareResults.html?
interestRateType='.$_POST["interestRateType"].'&occupation='.$_POST["occupation"].'&offeringTypeId='.$_POST["offeringID"].
'&city='.$_POST["city"].'&loanAmt='.$_POST["loanAmt"].'&age='.$_POST["age"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this because there is some `'` and `.` error

```
$url = 'http://www.aaa.com/ajaxv2/getCompareResults.html?
        interestRateType='.$_POST["interestRateType"].'&
        occupation='.$_POST["occupation"].'&
        offeringTypeId='.$_POST["offeringID"].'&
        city='.$_POST["city"].'&
        loanAmt='.$_POST["loanAmt"].'&
        age='.$_POST["age"];
```

Comment: That's Great .. !!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. You have syntax error before `&occupation`

```
$url = 'http://www.aaa.com/ajaxv2/getCompareResults.html?interestRateType='.$_POST["interestRateType"].'&occupation='.$_POST["occupation"].'&offeringTypeId='.$_POST["offeringID"].'&city='.$_POST["city"].'&loanAmt='.$_POST["loanAmt"].'&age='.$_POST["age"];
```